# Best way to backup remote windows 2008 server to my local machine?

Tags: windows-server-2008, backup-restoration

We have a remote Windows 2008 server hosted by 1&1 which I would like to backup to my local desktop.  What are some of the better alternatives to accomplish this?  Daily automatic backups would be nice and a complete recovery would also be desired.  I currently have about 30GB of data.  My client machine is currently a Windows XP.  I have a relatively fast cable broadband connection.

Thank you,
Jim

Comment: You should probably tell us what the client machine is running, as that will affect what is suitable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its very difficult to do a remote backup. then also if u need to backup , according to me you have two ways.

1)Connect to the server remotely with your local drives attached and do a manual backup every day.

2) second method requires a public IP in ur client machine. and u have a to map a network drive to the server and do a automated backup.

the above methods dont require any third party apps. But the 30 GB data is not that small to do a remote backup.

Comment: Not sure how that link is relevant...?